# Error launching .NET application compiled to target 'Any CPU'

Tags: .net, vb.net, x86, 64-bit

I have a .NET application that is shared to around 30 different computers, (mix of 32-bit and 64-bit machines).

When compiled, the application is set to target 'Any CPU'.

It runs fine on all machines except one that is Windows 7 64 bit.

The error message is:

> Following errors were detected during this operation.  * [11/2/2011
>   8:59:40 AM] System.ArgumentException
>     - Value does not fall within the expected range.
>     - Source: System.Deployment

After researching, I found that if I change the target CPU to 64-bit it runs fine on the problem machine, but will not run on the 32-bit computers.

Is there a fix for this?

Stack trace:

```
- Stack trace:
    at System.Deployment.Internal.Isolation.IStore.LockApplicationPath(UInt32 Flags, IDefinitionAppId ApId, IntPtr& Cookie)
    at System.Deployment.Application.ComponentStore.LockApplicationPath(DefinitionAppId definitionAppId)
    at System.Deployment.Application.SubscriptionStore.LockApplicationPath(DefinitionAppId definitionAppId)
    at System.Deployment.Application.FileDownloader.PatchFiles(SubscriptionState subState)
    at System.Deployment.Application.FileDownloader.Download(SubscriptionState subState)
    at System.Deployment.Application.DownloadManager.DownloadDependencies(SubscriptionState subState, AssemblyManifest deployManifest, AssemblyManifest appManifest, Uri sourceUriBase, String targetDirectory, String group, IDownloadNotification notification, DownloadOptions options)
    at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.DownloadApplication(SubscriptionState subState, ActivationDescription actDesc, Int64 transactionId, TempDirectory& downloadTemp)
    at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.InstallApplication(SubscriptionState& subState, ActivationDescription actDesc)
    at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.PerformDeploymentActivation(Uri activationUri, Boolean isShortcut, String textualSubId, String deploymentProviderUrlFromExtension, BrowserSettings browserSettings, String& errorPageUrl)
    at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.ActivateDeploymentWorker(Object state)
```

Comment: When does this exception occur?  When running the app or when installing it?

Comment: it is an online only application: application cannot be started. contact application vendor. so when it is trying to first run

Comment: You need to post the stack trace of the exception.

Comment: edited question with the stack trace

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A highly relevant thread found on MSDN forum is *[ClickOnce Fails with "Value does not fall within the expected range."](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/winformssetup/thread/9e4b714e-bad4-4c62-a7ad-3c80e32d95eb)*

Comment: I read this before, that is where i got the target cpu information from. The problem is, i have a mix of 32bit and 64bit applications that use a mysql system dsn (odbc data source), i can install the 32bit version under odbccard32 in syswow64, but this creates a whole new issues with other programs etc.

Comment: read this again and followed some reference steps, fixed issue thanks!